# Property Observers on NSUserDefaults

Tags: swift

I have a group of buttons, and when two buttons are pressed, then an NSUserDefault is triggered,but I need an observer in the ViewController to do some animation.

Is this possible in swift ? Could I use DidSet: and WillSet: or is there an other option ?

Comment: Have you simply tried DidSet?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way to do that is to combine both user defaults and animations on a computed variable as follow:

```
var defaultName:String{
    get {

        var returnValue: NSString? = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("defaultName") as? NSString

        if returnValue == nil //Check for first run of app
        {
            returnValue = ""
        }
        return returnValue!
    }

    set (newValue) {
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(newValue, forKey: "defaultName")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
        // start your animations here
    }
}
```

Next on button click just change the defaultName value so both newValue will be stored and animations will trigger

Comment: Hi there thanks, I have the buttons on one VC and the animation and data connection on another... is this still possible ?

Comment: If you use data as computed properties (as I described above) you can put variables in every view controller and if one of these variables change its value, all the others will be automatically updated. If you use value of these store properties to update your view then just put all these updates on viewVillAppear method